# Affine open subsets of elliptic curves

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $A$ be a finite set of closed points of an elliptic curve $E$ (over an algebraically closed field). My question is that is the open subset $U=E\backslash A$ affine?

Hints and references are all welcome. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @reuns I may be wrong, but I think more commonly *affine* means something isomorphic to a Zariski closed subset of $\overline{K}^n$.... (or even just the spec of a commutative ring). Think: $x$-axis minus the origin is isomorphic to the plane curve $xy=1$.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Ok, tks. I don't even understand Nicolas's answer.

Comment: @reuns a map $X \to \Bbb P^n$ is more or less determined by the locus $X \cap H$ where $H \subset \Bbb P^n$ is an hyperplane which do not contains $X$. Conversely if there is a "nice" divisor $D$ (the technical term is very ample) then I can find a map $X \to \Bbb P^n$ such that $D$ is an hyperplane section of $X$. If you are interested, the book by R. Miranda is very well made and do lot of nice computations with divisors on curves.

Comment: @NicolasHemelsoet The "corresponding embedding" is to send each point $x \in C$ to $(f_1(x),\ldots,f_m(x))$ where $f_1,\ldots,f_m$ is a basis of $L(n. P)$ ? By definition of $L(n.P)$, the poles of $f_1,\ldots,f_m$ are at $x \in P$ thus $(f_1(x),\ldots,f_m(x)) \in \overline{K}^m$ for $x \in C \setminus P$, and "very ample" would be about finding if for each $x \in P$, one of the $f_j$ is $\infty$ ?

Comment: Yes exactly for the corresponding embedding. But as you can see, if $D$ is arbitrary then this map might have several problem : first they can be no $f_i$, then they could all vanishes at the same point (so the map is not well-defined) and finally it could be not injective. $D$ is called very ample if $x \mapsto (f_1(x):\dots:f_m(x))$ is an embedding. A consequence of Riemann-Roch for curves says that if $D$ is an effective divisor (that is, $D$ has positive coefficient, for example $D = 2P$, then $nD$ is very ample for $n >> 0$.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, in fact for any projective curve $C$ and point $P \in C$, $C \backslash \{P\}$ is affine.

Indeed, by Riemann-Roch we have that $n \cdot P$ is a very ample divisor for $n$ big enough. For the corresponding embedding $\phi : C \to \Bbb P^m$, there will be an hyperplane $H$ with $H \cap C = n \cdot P$. In particular, $C \backslash \{P\} \subset \Bbb A^n$ is affine.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Since $C$ is separated, we can reduce the general case to the singleton case.