# Does any finite subset of a curve fit into an open affine?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves, arithmetic-geometry, singularity-theory

Let $C$ be an irreducible and non-singular algebraic curve over an algebraically closed field $k$, and let $S \subset C$ be any *finite* set of points. Is it true that there is always an open affine $U \subset C$, which contains all of $S$?

If $C$ is projective, this seems to be true, see [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2562764/31240). This also settles the case for quasi-projective curves.

Some context: I think this is implicitly used in Serre's *Algebraic Groups and Class Fields*. He wants to construct another curve $C'$, such that $C \to C'$ is the normalization of $C'$, and $S$ is the preimage of the singular points. He claims that it suffices to construct $C'$ for the affine case, and glue the affines together. However I think this only works if we find an affine which contains $S$.

Comment: Um, $C$ is always quasi-projective, isn’t it? Because $C$ is an open subset of a proper smooth curve (consider the set of $k$-valuations of its function field, endowed with the Zariski topology – that’s more a less a scheme minus the generic point, and it’s proper because of the valuative criterion. I think) and these are projective.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every curve is quasi-projective: see [Stacks 0A25](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0A25), for instance. One strategy for the proof is to find an ample line bundle, take a high-enough tensor power so that it becomes very ample, and get an immersion in to $\Bbb P^r_k$. In fact, $\mathcal{O}(p)$ for $p$ a smooth point will do for our ample line bundle: $\mathcal{O}(np)$ for $n\gg 0$ will be very ample by Riemann-Roch. (I'm sure that this is recounted somewhere here on MSE or MO, but I can't find it at the moment - if you are reading this and can find the link, please put it in the comments!)